# get object vars of extended class

Tags: php, json, class, inheritance

I have to encode with json the Cane class (php), the problem is that when I do that the json string result is without Animale class attributes.
it end to be only:    {"razza":"n/d"}1
how can I have the Animale class attribute and also the Cane attributes?
the code:

```
   class Animale implements \JsonSerializable{
        private $id;
        private $nome;
        protected function Animale($id=-1,$nome="n/d"){
            $this->id=$id;
            $this->nome=$nome;
        }
        public function jsonSerialize(){
            return get_object_vars($this);
        }
    }
    class Cane extends Animale implements \JsonSerializable{
        private $razza;
        function Cane($id=-1, $nome="n/d",$razza="n/d"){
            parent::Animale($id, $nome);
            $this->razza=$razza;
        }
        public function jsonSerialize(){
            return get_object_vars();
        }

    }
```

Please excuse my English; English isn't my first language.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change `private` variables to `protected` or `public`.